# Linux Mint terminal colors not working

Tags: terminal, vim, colors, xterm

I am trying to get xterm-256color working, but have not been successful.

I have LMDE 2 Betsy (Linux Mint Debian Edition) installed and am trying to learn to use vim. I installed a vim colorscheme, but the colors were off.  Looking online, I need to use xterm-256color instead of the default xterm. I have tried all combinations of information I could find, but have not been able to get it to work.

Combinations I've tried:

- `export TERM=xterm-256color` in terminal
- `export TERM=xterm256color` in .bashrc
- `set TERM=xterm-256color` in .vimrc
- `set t_Co=256` in .vimrc
- `env TERM=xterm-256color /bin/bash` in Run Application

`tput colors` gives me 256, `echo $TERM` gives me xterm-256color

`ncurses-terminal` is installed and exists on my machine

LMDE's default terminal is `mate-terminal`

I then installed `terminator` and `guake`, but they also don't work and their profile colors in settings only gives a 16 color palette, like the default terminal.

I have reloaded .bashrc and did a logout/login to refresh it, but nothing seems to override my terminal to provide me with 256 colors.

Any help or suggestions is appreciated!

**EDIT**

The "molokai" colorscheme from http://bytefluent.com/vivify/ should give me this result:
[image]

But, instead I get this:
[image]

Comment: What is it that makes you think you don't have 256 colors available? What is your expected behavior vs. actual behavior? E.g. in mate-terminal's or terminator's preference you'd still be able to set the first 16, since those are the ones that typically change according to the user's preference, the next 240 colors typically have a fixed RGB value.

Comment: I downloaded the vim "molokai" colorscheme from http://bytefluent.com/vivify/ and this is the result: http://imgur.com/gallery/AxFDB

Comment: The correct presentation should look like this screenshot: http://imgur.com/gallery/pzBad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was that I had to make sure to select the Vim version of the colorscheme download from http://bytefluent.com/vivify/.  I was downloading the wrong preset GVim version...

For anyone else wondering, the toggle is the top section of the right-hand sidebar on the site, near "Scheme Name>" and "Instructions".  Somehow, I missed that...